# How to communicate message from debugger to react native component?

Tags: react-native

Interested in knowing if there is a way of passing an event with some payload to react native components through debugger console in chrome.

My use case is, while debugging I want  to send a message to one of my react components.

Comment: web sockets connects the two, so in theory I would guess it's probably possible. have you tried? you might get a better response if you provided a more detailed and specific example

Comment: Updated question, btw RTWebsocket where socket receives messages, has didreceivemessage handler but is there an alternative?